# Python 3.3 Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, encryption

So I'm new to python coding language and my task is to encrypt a random user made message by a random keyword made by user. For example user inputs: Python and inputs a keyword: Help. So first letter of the message is P and first of keyword letter is H, this means that P should shift by the alphabetical position of H which is 8 so P now will become X. And the keyword must be used continuously until the encryption is complete. Here is my code:

```
def keyword():
  w=[7,3,19,5]
  x=""
  g = 0
  i=0
  w2=input ("Please enter a KeyWord: ")
  m=input ("Please enter a Message: ")
  for ch in m:
      en = chr(ord(ch)+ w2)
      shift = (ord (w2[i%len(w2)]))
      x= (x+en)
      print(str(x))

keyword()
```

And here is the output given:

```
    Please enter a KeyWord: lol
    Please enter a Message: lol
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
        keyword()
      File "H:\t2test.py", line 22, in keyword
        en = chr(ord(ch)+ w2)
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Now I'm trying to solve this problem and if you are going to say that w2 needs to be a integer and it can't encrypt - I know right now I'm looking for a way to make this code work. Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is homework? It looks like the question used a hard coded value for the *KeyWord* and your *task* was to make it an user input.

Comment: Its not 'homework' :DD I'm just learning the language and my friend suggested to try encryption.

Comment: Ok. I don't see how `en = chr(ord(ch)+ w2)` will help you. And see how you ignores the calculated value of `shift`. Also I guess you want to increment `i` as you loop (bonus points for using enumerate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ord(ch)` is a int, it should be a string

Try this:

```
num = str(ord(ch)) + w2
en = chr(int(num))
```

Comment: Let me try I will display the output

Comment: @ChipZ I thought, this answer didn't work (judging from your deleted answer and your edit). Why did you accept it?